# Use the values of the input fields in a group as the value of the last input field in the group

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to set the value of the last input field in a group, to equal the values of its siblings. In this scenario, users can duplicate the group.

What I have tried so far does not work properly. If user duplicates the fields, only the last group works. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

```js
var addition = $(".duplicate");
var perQuestion = $(".per-question");

$(function() {

  addition.on("click", function() {

    perQuestion.first().clone().insertBefore(".per-question:first");

    $(".per-question").each(function() {

      var index = $(this).index() + 1;
      $(this).find(".questionNumber").text(index);
    });

  });


});
```

```css
.per-question {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.duplicate {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #0966bd;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="duplicate">+</div>

<div class="main" ng-app="">

  <div class="per-question">
    <div class="questionNumber"></div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="q1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="q2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="q3">

    <input type="text" name="toDb" value="{{q1}},{{q2}},{{q3}}" id="toDB">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend getting rid of your `jQuery` function and doing everything in `AngularJS`.  You will need to do the following:

1. Move your button inside of your `ng-app`.
2. Track an array of questions, and use `ng-repeat` to generate `per-question`
3. HTML for each one.
4. Initiate said array so it starts with an empty question.
   Add an `ng-click` handler to your button that appends a new blank question to the questions array.

If you want to have `q1` be shared across all questions, you can define it on the `$parent` scope, which will point to the scope that is outside of the `ng-repeat` directive.

*At this point, I would normally recommend using a `controller` and the `controllerAs` syntax, rather than using `$parent` and `ng-init` to set up variables and scoping.*

```css
.per-question {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.duplicate {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #0966bd;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- define a starting collection of questions -->
<div ng-app="" ng-init="questions = [{}]">
    <!-- Use angular to push a new question to the array, ng-repeat will automatically render it -->
    <div class="duplicate" ng-click="questions.push({})">+</div>
    
    <div class="main">
      <!-- iterate over questions, showing a group for each one -->
      <div class="per-question" ng-repeat="question in questions">
        <div class="questionNumber"></div>
        <!-- q1 is defined on the parent scope (outside the ng-repeat) -->
        <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.q1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="question.q2">
        <input type="text" ng-model="question.q3">
    
        <input type="text" name="toDb" value="{{$parent.q1}},{{question.q2}},{{question.q3}}" id="toDB-{{$index}}">
    
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I get the first filed in each group to have the same value? This is because the value of the first field in each group remains.

Comment: `ng-repeat` creates a separate scope for each question.  If `q1` is supposed to be shared across all questions, you can either use `$parent.q1` to access a `q1` variable defined outside the `ng-repeat`, or you can create a controller and use `controller as` syntax to get appropriate variable scoping.

Comment: OKay, I will try that.

Comment: Updated my answer to include that.  Overall, I think you are going to want to create a controller to manage your state, rather than trying to do it in the HTML.  As you start nesting stuff, using `$parent` is going to become more difficult, but being able to just reference a property on the parent controller will still work fine.